# How to copy directory from source tree to binary tree?

Tags: c, copy, cmake

Copying directory from source tree to binary tree. For example: How to copy www to bin folder.

```
work
├─bin
└─src
    ├─doing
    │  └─www
    ├─include
    └─lib
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

With CMake 2.8 or later, use the [`file(COPY ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#copy) command.

With CMake versions below 2.8, the following macro copies files from one directory to another.  If you don't want to substitute variables in the copied files, then change the configure_file `@ONLY` argument (for example to `COPYONLY`).

```
# Copy files from source directory to destination directory, substituting any
# variables.  Create destination directory if it does not exist.

macro(configure_files srcDir destDir)
    message(STATUS "Configuring directory ${destDir}")
    make_directory(${destDir})

    file(GLOB templateFiles RELATIVE ${srcDir} "${srcDir}/*")
    foreach(templateFile ${templateFiles})
        set(srcTemplatePath ${srcDir}/${templateFile})
        if(NOT IS_DIRECTORY ${srcTemplatePath})
            message(STATUS "Configuring file ${templateFile}")
            configure_file(
                    ${srcTemplatePath}
                    ${destDir}/${templateFile}
                    @ONLY)
        endif(NOT IS_DIRECTORY ${srcTemplatePath})
    endforeach(templateFile)
endmacro(configure_files)
```

Comment: It's easy to copy file or directory when use cmake -E mode.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Edited because this is the accepted answer and the other answer with the file(COPY command is cleaner.

Comment: Yeah, but can you run file(COPY...) as a custom command that depends on the target?

Comment: file(GLOB_RECURSE ..) for subdirectories

Answer (score 152):

Since version 2.8, the [`file` command has a `COPY` sub-command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#copy):

```
file(COPY yourDir DESTINATION yourDestination)
```

Note that:

> Relative input paths are evaluated with respect to the current source
> directory, and a relative destination is evaluated with respect to the
> current build directory

Comment: This looks promising. Can you explain how you get this to trigger, or does it run every time?

Comment: it only works when running cmake command, not during actual build time

Comment: What if I want to check whether the directory is already there in the destination?

Answer (score 46):

As nobody has mentioned `cmake -E copy_directory` as a custom target, here's what I've used:

```
add_custom_target(copy-runtime-files ALL
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/runtime-files-dir ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/runtime-files-dir
    DEPENDS ${MY_TARGET})
```

Comment: Short and easy, great. If you drop `DEPENDS ${MY_TARGET}` this can run in parallel to the compiling process. Keep in mind that files are copied every time `make` is running, so it might have limitations with very big folders.

Comment: I get `Expected a command name, got unquoted argument with text "/runtime-files-dir".` for this :(

Comment: This is the preferred solution for me because it works with usage of $<CONFIG>

Answer (score 28):

The `configure` command will only copy files when `cmake` is run. Another option is to create a new target, and use the custom_command option. Here's one that I use (if you run it more than once, you'll have to modify the `add_custom_target` line to make it unique for each call).

```
macro(copy_files GLOBPAT DESTINATION)
  file(GLOB COPY_FILES
    RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    ${GLOBPAT})
  add_custom_target(copy ALL
    COMMENT "Copying files: ${GLOBPAT}")

  foreach(FILENAME ${COPY_FILES})
    set(SRC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${FILENAME}")
    set(DST "${DESTINATION}/${FILENAME}")

    add_custom_command(
      TARGET copy
      COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${SRC} ${DST}
      )
  endforeach(FILENAME)
endmacro(copy_files)
```

Comment: I adapted your (amazing) answer to have a more modular script. See my answer !

Comment: Note that this (now ten years old!!) answer predates generator expressions in CMake, as well as the `copy_directory` command.

Answer (score 16):

Use execute_process and call cmake -E. If you want a deep copy, you can use the `copy_directory` command. Even better, you could create a `symlink` (if your platform supports it) with the create_symlink command. The latter can be achieved like this:

```
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E create_symlink ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/www
                                                           ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/path/to/www)
```

From: http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2009-March/028299.html

Comment: The only issue with this is it breaks the concept of out-of-source builds if temp files are produced in the directory.

Answer (score 2):

Thank! That is really helpful advice to use bunch of add_custom_target and add_custom_command. I wrote the following function to use everywhere in my projects. Is also specifies the installation rule. I use it primarily to export interface header files.

```
#
# export file: copy it to the build tree on every build invocation and add rule for installation
#
function    (cm_export_file FILE DEST)
  if    (NOT TARGET export-files)
    add_custom_target(export-files ALL COMMENT "Exporting files into build tree")
  endif (NOT TARGET export-files)
  get_filename_component(FILENAME "${FILE}" NAME)
  add_custom_command(TARGET export-files COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${FILE}" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${DEST}/${FILENAME}")
  install(FILES "${FILE}" DESTINATION "${DEST}")
endfunction (cm_export_file)
```

Usage looks like this:

```
cm_export_file("API/someHeader0.hpp" "include/API/")
cm_export_file("API/someHeader1.hpp" "include/API/")
```

Comment: This looks interesting. Can it copy entire directories?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer from Seth Johnson; wrote for more convenience:

```
# Copy files
macro(resource_files files)
    foreach(file ${files})
        message(STATUS "Copying resource ${file}")
        file(COPY ${file} DESTINATION ${Work_Directory})
    endforeach()
endmacro()

# Copy directories
macro(resource_dirs dirs)
    foreach(dir ${dirs})
        # Replace / at the end of the path (copy dir content VS copy dir)
        string(REGEX REPLACE "/+$" "" dirclean "${dir}")
        message(STATUS "Copying resource ${dirclean}")
        file(COPY ${dirclean} DESTINATION ${Work_Directory})
    endforeach()
endmacro()
```