# CMake: How to copy only specific file extensions from one directory into another

Tags: c++, cmake

I am using the following custom command to copy all the files within the `config` directory into the `build` directory. The problem is that I don't want the `.svn` directory to be copied as well. I am looking for a way to either exclude the `.svn` directory or to copy files with specific extension. e.g. I want only files with `xml` or `conf` extensions to be copied. What should I do?

```
add_custom_command(TARGET MyTarget PRE_BUILD
                   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
                       ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/config $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:MyTarget>)
```

[related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13429656/69537)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To copy just the `.xml` and `.conf` files, you can use the [`file(GLOB ...)`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command:file) command:

```
# Gather list of all .xml and .conf files in "/config"
file(GLOB ConfigFiles ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/config/*.xml
                      ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/config/*.conf)

foreach(ConfigFile ${ConfigFiles})
  add_custom_command(TARGET MyTarget PRE_BUILD
                     COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E
                         copy ${ConfigFile} $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:MyTarget>)
endforeach()
```

It's a similar process to get all files not in the `.svn` subdirectory:

```
# Gather list of all files in "/config"
file(GLOB ConfigFiles RELATIVE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/config
     ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/config/*)

# Gather list of all files in "/config/.svn"
file(GLOB SvnConfigFiles RELATIVE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/config 
     ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/config/.svn/*)

# Remove ".svn" and its contents from the list
list(REMOVE_ITEM ConfigFiles .svn ${SvnConfigFiles})

foreach(ConfigFile ${ConfigFiles})
  add_custom_command(TARGET MyTarget PRE_BUILD
                     COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E
                         copy ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/config/${ConfigFile}
                              $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:MyTarget>)
endforeach()
```

Comment: Instead of merging list of files, it seems that it's possible to write all file types in one line.

Comment: Is it possible to have a target for copying files without compiling? Something like "make copy" which only copies config files.

Comment: I just saw this comment now and have already [answered it here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14475005/424459) :-)

Comment: I have the same problem, but I need to GLOB after the build. How to do it?

Comment: @Nick Best to ask a new question - it's too much for a comment.