# CMake: How to have a target for copying files

Tags: cmake

I am using the following command to copy config files into the build directory after each compile.

```
# Gather list of all .xml and .conf files in "/config"
file(GLOB ConfigFiles ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/config/*.xml
                      ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/config/*.conf)

foreach(ConfigFile ${ConfigFiles})
  add_custom_command(TARGET MyTarget PRE_BUILD
                     COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E
                         copy ${ConfigFile} $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:MyTarget>)
endforeach()
```

This action is triggered every time I compile the project. Is it possible to create a target in CMakeLists.txt to copy files without needing to compile anything? Something like "make copy".

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should be able to add a new custom target called `copy` and make that the target of your custom commands:

```
file(GLOB ConfigFiles ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/config/*.xml
                      ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/config/*.conf)

add_custom_target(copy)
foreach(ConfigFile ${ConfigFiles})
  add_custom_command(TARGET copy PRE_BUILD
                     COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E
                         copy ${ConfigFile} $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:MyTarget>)
endforeach()
```

Now the custom commands will only execute if you build `copy`.

If you want to keep this `copy` target as a dependency of `MyTarget` so that you can either just copy the files or have them copied if you build `MyTarget`, you'll need to break the cyclic dependency.  (`MyTarget` depends on `copy`, but `copy` depends on `MyTarget` to get the location of the copy-to directory).

To do this, you can resort to the old-fashioned way of getting a target's output directory:

```
add_custom_target(copy)
get_target_property(MyTargetLocation MyTarget LOCATION)
get_filename_component(MyTargetDir ${MyTargetLocation} PATH)
foreach(ConfigFile ${ConfigFiles})
  add_custom_command(TARGET copy PRE_BUILD
                     COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E
                         copy ${ConfigFile} ${MyTargetDir})
endforeach()
add_dependencies(MyTarget copy)
```

Comment: Thank you. Do I need two separate `add_custom_command` command? one for the main executable target and one for copy target? Because right now the custom command is something like this: `add_custom_command(TARGET ${PRODUCT} PRE_BUILD`. I want files to be copied either when I make the main target or when I do "make copy".

Comment: @Meysam In that case, use `add_dependencies(${PRODUCT} copy)` to make `${PRODUCT}` depend on `copy`.

Comment: Is it possible to implement this in terms of `FILE(COPY ...)` command of CMake?