# Cycling on part of the arguments of a macro in cmake

Tags: cmake

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14475005/2436175), I was trying to create a [macro](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command:macro) that would copy at build time a list of files.

```
macro   (copy_files_at_build_time targetname) #usage: copy_files_at_build_time(<targetname> <file> [<files>] <destination>)
    if(ARGC LESS 3)
        message(ERROR "copy_files_at_build_time called with less than 3 arguments")
    endif(ARGC LESS 3)
    MATH(EXPR LAST_INDEX "${ARGC}-2")
    MATH(EXPR DEST_INDEX "${ARGC}-1")
    set(MY_DESTINATION ${ARGV${DEST_INDEX}})
    foreach(I RANGE 1 ${LAST_INDEX})
        message (STATUS "${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${ARGV${I}} ${MY_DESTINATION}")
        add_custom_command(TARGET ${targetname} PRE_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different ${ARGV${I}} ${MY_DESTINATION})
    endforeach(I)
endmacro(copy_files_at_build_time)
```

As you can see there is a debug message, and unfortunately both `${ARGV${I}}` and `${MY_DESTINATION}` (which is `${ARGV${DEST_INDEX}}`) are empty when I print them. So, it seems that is not possible to access to ARGV1, ARGV2 etc. (see [macro documentation](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command:macro)) by using a variable as last part of the variable name. I will now implement a workaround using the [list](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command:list) commands, but my question is:

Is there an easier way to cycle on the ARGV0, ARGV1, ARGV2 elements, if some of the elements (e.g. the first and the last) have to be skipped?

**Edit**

Sadly enough, I am seeing that not even the LIST commands work on ARGV! But they work if first I create a copy of ARGV and then perform the LIST commands on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the implementation I ended up with, I am open to better solutions!
Note: the second function (the one that copies also directories) is probably safer in case some of the destination directories did not exist.

```
macro   (copy_files_at_build_time targetname) #usage: copy_files_at_build_time(<targetname> <file> [<files>] <destination>)
    if(ARGC LESS 3)
        message(ERROR "copy_files_at_build_time called with less than 3 arguments")
    endif(ARGC LESS 3)
    SET(ARGN_COPY ${ARGN})
    MATH(EXPR DEST_INDEX "${ARGC}-2") #It should be "${ARGC}-1", but we are using ARGN that doesn't contain the first element of the list
    list(GET ARGN_COPY ${DEST_INDEX} MY_DESTINATION)
    list(REMOVE_AT ARGN_COPY ${DEST_INDEX})
    foreach(MY_FILE ${ARGN_COPY})
#       message (STATUS "${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different ${MY_FILE} ${MY_DESTINATION}")
        add_custom_command(TARGET ${targetname} PRE_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different ${MY_FILE} ${MY_DESTINATION})
    endforeach(MY_FILE)
endmacro(copy_files_at_build_time)
```

**If we want to copy also directories** (beware: not tested if it works recursively!)

```
macro   (copy_at_build_time targetname) #usage: copy_at_build_time(<targetname> <file|directory> [<files|directories>] <destination>)
    if(ARGC LESS 3)
        message(ERROR "copy_files_at_build_time called with less than 3 arguments")
    endif(ARGC LESS 3)
    SET(ARGN_COPY ${ARGN})
    MATH(EXPR DEST_INDEX "${ARGC}-2") #It should be "${ARGC}-1", but we are using ARGN that doesn't contain the first element of the list
    list(GET ARGN_COPY ${DEST_INDEX} MY_DESTINATION)
    list(REMOVE_AT ARGN_COPY ${DEST_INDEX})
    foreach(MY_FILE ${ARGN_COPY})
        get_filename_component(LEAF_NAME "${MY_FILE}" NAME)
        if (IS_DIRECTORY ${MY_FILE})
            add_custom_command(TARGET ${targetname} PRE_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory ${MY_FILE} ${MY_DESTINATION}/${LEAF_NAME})
        else(IS_DIRECTORY ${MY_FILE})
            add_custom_command(TARGET ${targetname} PRE_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different ${MY_FILE} ${MY_DESTINATION}/${LEAF_NAME})
        endif(IS_DIRECTORY ${MY_FILE})
    endforeach(MY_FILE)
endmacro(copy_at_build_time)
```

Comment: The only small improvement that I can see is to define e FUNCTION that does the ARGV copy. That only makes the code a little more clear.

Comment: @GabrielPetrovay You mean for just the line `SET(ARGN_COPY ${ARGN})`? I wouldn't use a function for that...

Comment: I meant SET MATH LIST LIST. And of course it depends if you use it in more macros or not. Otherwise it doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2):

`${ARGV${DEST_INDEX}})` is not supported in MACROS (at least form my experience). You must perform `LIST(...)` operations to handle the MACRO arguments using the `${ARGV}` list of arguments.

Use either:

- `LIST(REMOVE_AT, ...)` or similar list operations to remove arguments or
- iterate using `FOREACH(loop_var IN ...)`