# How copy files once before update on build via CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, copy, shared-libraries, project

I have a set of external shared objects. For example `*.dll`. There are seprate builds created for debug and release in foldars `./external/Debug` and `./external/Release`. I have a simple Cmake project. I want to copy contents of external folders on build if they have changed. How to do such thing in crossplatform manner using cmake?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake: How to have a target for copying files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474659/cmake-how-to-have-a-target-for-copying-files)

Comment: I think Amadeus is right.