# Add files with target using CMake

Tags: c, cmake

I am working using `CMake` on a little C project using `OpenGL`. To be able to run, my executable needs to access some resources files such as 3D meshes, textures or shader program sources.

When I run the generated executable, the current folder is the directory where it is created. This directory may differ depending on the binary tree location (out of source ? insource ? anywhere in the coputer). But my resources are located near my source tree.

I would like my `CMakeLists.txt` to copy the resource folder in my executable output directory but I have not a good idea of the way to do that. Besides, I am not sure this is a "best practice" of CMake.

Thank you for reading :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 useful variable to do so: `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` and `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`, the former refers to the current `CMakeLists.txt` output directory, the latter refers to the top level project output directory.

Most of the time, you handle resources near the executable depending on it, then you'll certainly want to refer to `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR`.

```
configure_file(
  "MyResourceDir/myresource"
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/" COPYONLY
)
```

This command will copy resource of the `CURRENT_CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR/MyResourceDir` named `myresource` in the directory matching the current `CMakeLists.txt`.

You can glob files of your `MyResourceDir` and loop on it (maybe there is also some function to copy directory instead of list of files).

Comment: Your answer helped me finding the right way to express my needs. Indeed I need to copy a whole directory and subdirectories to the binary direction. `configure_file` is a good idea and i found an other way of doing what I need : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429656/cmake-how-to-copy-contents-of-a-directory-into-build-directory-after-make