# CMake include resources in build

Tags: windows, cmake

Using CMake, how do I put resources in a folder along with the build?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

set(TARGET_NAME test-api)

add_executable(
    ${TARGET_NAME} 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Test.cpp
)

add_custom_command(TARGET ${TARGET_NAME} POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/test_resources
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test_resources ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/test_resources
)
```

I noticed that if I have the following folder structure:

```
/root
    /bin
        /Debug
        /Release
```

CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY points to /bin.

CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG points to /Debug.

CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE points to /Release.

I'd like to copy the test_resources to /Debug when I'm building debug and copy to /Release when I'm building Release. How do I do that?

Comment: `file(GENERATE)` [command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#generate) can help here

Comment: Definitely sounds like the direction where I want to go :). Can I use it also to create new folders?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy contents of a directory into build directory after make with CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429656/how-to-copy-contents-of-a-directory-into-build-directory-after-make-with-cmake) You should use generator expressions as suggested in the first answer, which will be configuration-aware, and copy into the Debug or Release directory appropriately.