# variable for standard output dir in CMake for VS 19

Tags: c++, cmake, optix

I am an absolute noob when it comes to CMake and have been stuck on this problem for the last three days.
The OptiX application I am working on reads in a .ptx file compiled from a .cu file.
I am struggling to get the file to be compiled into the same directory as the .exe is.

I didn't set up the CMake file so I am trying to adapt the SDK examples.
The .exe get's compiled into bin/release/ or bin/debug without a problem.

I want the .ptx to be compiled to bin/release/ptx or bin/debug/ptx depending on the build mode in VS. Is there a variable which lets me access the bin/release bin/debug paths?
Best I could do is ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY} which get's me the bin/ folder.
(If it helps, a pastebin of the root [CMakeLists.txt](https://pastebin.com/VW66x2fq), line 252:

```
set(SAMPLES_PTX_DIR "${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE}")
```

Thank you for help, I hope I could make myself clear enough!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy DLL files into the same folder as the executable using CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671916/how-to-copy-dll-files-into-the-same-folder-as-the-executable-using-cmake) I think the some of the responses here apply directly to your situation. Specifically, you can use the generator expression `$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:YourTarget>/ptx`.

Comment: For me just a ${???} pointing to default output directory of VS would do the trick. I don't know if there exists such a command. I tried some of the solutions, but can't get the file in the correct directory.

Comment: That's essentially what `$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:YourTarget>` will do. It points to the directory containing your built `YourTarget` target, which will change depending on your VS Configuration (Debug or Release).

Comment: Wow thank you so much!
I ended up using this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429656/how-to-copy-contents-of-a-directory-into-build-directory-after-make-with-cmake)