# Resource Folder In Cmake

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I have a project like this:

```
- root/
    - main/
        - include/
            - *.h
        - res/
            - *.txt
        - src/
            - *.c
        CMakeListst.txt
    - CMakeLists.txt
```

The `res` folder is the folder with a bunch of text files which my application reads.

This is how my `root/CMakeLists.txt` looks like:

```
// Configuration stuff

add_subdirectory(main)
```

Then `root/main/CMakeLists.txt` looks like:

```
include_directories(include)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES *.c)
file(GLOB_RECURSE RESOURCES *.txt)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${RESOURCES} ${SOURCES})
```

I thought I could add all the resources to the `add_executable` statement, but then I debugged my program and I found out it crashed when I tried to open the file. Lets say I have a file called `foo.txt` in the `res/` folder, then when I do `fopen("foo.txt", "r");` it returns null. How can I add custom resources?

Comment: fopen does not anything in common with Cmake. What do you want to archive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you misunderstand what `add_executable` does. It will generally just pass the files specified in it to the compiler.

As the compiler presumably doesn't know how to process your `foo.txt`, it ignores it (i'm actually surprised that it does not complain). What happens in your CMakeLists file is roughly equivalent to something like

```sh
gcc src/*.c res/*.txt
```

... which might make clear why it didn't do what you wanted it to (if you're familiar with gcc, not sure about your platform).

So, how can you "add" resources? Well, there are multiple ways:

- If you run your executable from the `root/main` directory, you can just open it like:

```c
FILE* my_file = fopen("res/foo.txt", "r");
```

or otherwise provide a relative or full path to your file. This is probably the best way.

- You can make cmake copy your "foo.txt" to the build directory (and then do what I said in the previous point). That way it's always in the same spot relative to your executable. [Here's a link I found that explains this fairly well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429656/how-to-copy-contents-of-a-directory-into-build-directory-after-make-with-cmake)
- You can embed the resources in your binary directly. I personally wouldn't do this unless there was a very good reason why the others *can't* be used. Generally this should also only be done for very small resources. I'm just putting this here for completeness. A library that can do this is [hexembed](https://github.com/codeplea/hexembed).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! The only thing is if I give a full path then on another machine it might now work. How do make one standard path that will work anywhere?

Comment: Do what I said in the second bulletpoint then, where you make cmake copy the files to the executable directory. You can then ship your program together with the res folder :)