make Cmake copy built executables and etc to a sensible path regardless of IDE/environment? (visual studio, gcc and etc)
i am working on a C++ application that is intended to be crossplatform.
I am using this template: https://github.com/Snowblaze/sdl2-cmake-starter
And i want to add a few changes, which so far is usually "disregarded" by Visual Studio.
i.e. modifying CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR doesn't really help.
My question in a nutshell:
How do i implement the following?:
[pseudo code]
copy *.* From $PROJECT_ROOT_DIR/src/assets to $PROJECT_ROOT_DIR/bin/build_type/
copy $OUTPUT_FILES to $PROJECT_ROOT_DIR/bin/build_type/

"build_type" is appended to the path by visual studio and i have a few files and a folder that needs to be copied to the same place as the executable, preferably ending up in a reasonable path, such as /project_name/bin/build_type/.
I'm struggling to find a way to implement a solution that works with various setups, i.e: GCC, Visual Studio, etc
Any help would be appreciated.

There are many questions on Stack Overflow which covers different aspects of copying files to build directory. I have marked your question as a duplicate of one of such question. If you wonder about particular aspect of such copying (e.g. "copy all files from the directory", or "copy dlls") then focus your question post on that aspect. But make sure that given aspect isn't covered in existing questions on Stack Overflow.

Nothing seemed to mention Visual Studio so it didn't seem like it would apply.
The post was very helpful though, I do think i have gotten things to work as intended now. thanks.

Specifically this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55208743/25094007
