# Installing additional files with CMake

Tags: c, cmake, opencl

I am attempting to supply some "source" files with some executables. I was wondering if there was a way to copy these source files to the build directory (From the source directory) then to the install directory using CMake.

My more specific goal here is to include OpenCL kernels that I write in their own *.cl files.

Example:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

Now my directory should have an executable (standard CMake) and `some_opencl_kernel.cl` which I open in my executable.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can copy the file to your build tree using [`add_custom_command`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html) by adding something like the following:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET MyExe POST_BUILD
                   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
                       ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/some_opencl_kernel.cl
                       $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:MyExe>
                   )
```

This adds a post-build event to your target (I've called it `MyExe`) which copies the file `src/some_opencl_kernel.cl` to the same directory in your build tree as your executable.

There are various other ways of copying a file into the build tree, but I like this one since it uses the "generator expression" `$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:MyExe>` to identify the location of the executable's directory in the build tree. This can vary depending on e.g. build-type or platform, so the generator expression is about the most reliable, cross-platform way of specifying this location I feel.

As for installing, you can just use the [`install(FILES ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html) command. Assuming for your executable you have something like:

```
install(TARGETS MyExe RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
```

you can just add:

```
install(FILES src/some_opencl_kernel.cl DESTINATION bin)
```

which will install it to `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin/some_opencl_kernel.cl` alongside the executable.

Comment: Fraser I really appreciate this, I was wondering if you had any thoughts on using the `configure_file` with the `COPYONLY`?

Comment: That works too and is the easiest option if you're not copying to the build dir where the exes/libs are being put, or if that dir is fixed.  For example, MSVC appends a "Debug" dir to the [`RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#prop_tgt:RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY) for Debug builds.  If you're never going to be using a multi-configuration generator, this is maybe not an issue for you, and `configure_file` would be a simpler option.

Comment: @Fraser I [read in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697560/how-to-copy-directory-from-source-tree-to-binary-tree#comment9222277_699752) that though soft linking a directory with such resource files to `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` works, it breaks the concept of _out-of-source_ builds, why?  How is copying any different? I'm asking this out of curiosity, your inputs would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

If you want to copy a folder's tree with some type of files:

```
  # Copy all assets to resources file
  INSTALL(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/assets/ DESTINATION ${INSTALL_PATH}/assets
          FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.dae"  PATTERN "*.jpg")
```

If you want to copy all files in folders, just remove the FILES_MATCHING patterns.