# Pretend headers are in a certain subdirectory?

Tags: c++, cmake

*Note: I'm currently tinkering with more modern CMake styles, not trying to accomodate an existing project. I'd consider alternative approaches to what I am doing as perfectly acceptable as long as they are scalable (i.e., downstream target shouldn't need to know about the internals of the upstream target).*

Let's say I have two targets in the same CMake build, `down` and `up`, where `down` depends on `up`:

```
target_link_libraries(down PUBLIC up)
```

Let's say the headers of `up` are inside `up/src/`:

```
+---up
    +---CMakeLists.txt
    +---src
        +---header.hpp
        +---<other headers/sources>
```

Now let's say that inside `down` I want to include the headers of `up` like so:

```cpp
// down/foo.cpp

#include "up/header.hpp"
```

If `down` is an external dependency (i.e. in a separate CMake build), that's easy: I just have to install all the headers of `up` in some kind of `include/up/` directory and then use that:

```
target_include_directories(up
  INTERFACE
    "$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include/up>")
```

But what if `down` is part of the *same* CMake build as `up`? I want to uniformize the code; I ***don't*** want `down`'s sources to have to do any of...

```cpp
#include "up/src/header.hpp"
#include "src/header.hpp"
#include "header.hpp"
```

The headers of `up` wouldn't be installed inside `include/up` until after all the targets, *including `down`*, would be built, since `down` is inside the same CMake build.

Is that sort of thing even possible without using horrible manual file copies? Should I just put all `up`'s sources inside a `up/src/up/` directory then?

My motivation is: `up` might be depended on by libraries both inside and outside the CMake build, so I want to uniformize the code accross internal and external targets.

Comment: _I'd consider alternative approaches to what I am doing_  Have you tried bazel?

Comment: @Taekahn Nope, never have. I'd really want a CMake solution without having to rely on a specific generator (one of CMake's goals is to be mostly generator-independant), but is there any particular reason why you're suggesting this? I suppose that would allow a solution?

Comment: Related: [Include headers with same name but from different libraries using CMake](/q/74879035), and [this](/a/74593941).

Comment: What about using a `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/${PROJECT_NAME}/{up,down}/<header files>` structure? Read `{up,down}` as two folders at that level, and `<header files>` as the header files for each of those targets. After all, that is quite a common CMake project structure. Once you add the `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/${PROJECT_NAME}` folder to both the `up` and `down` target include directories, you can `#include "up/blah.h"`.

Comment: @AnthonyD973 The reason i was suggesting it because it should be easy to do what you're asking in it. There is both a `include_path` _and_ a `strip_include_path` to "relocate" things.

Comment: @rturrado Hmmm... Yes, that seems to be a good approach. That `include/` directory would also be the location of the `PUBLIC` headers of the various libraries of the project, this way the `PRIVATE` headers could directly go into the source directory along with the `.cpp` files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `#include "up/header.hpp"` to work, then the file `header.hpp` should be **physically** located in the directory `up`. This is how all major compilers work, so CMake simply cannot "emulate" location of a header file.

However, it is quite easy to copy headers into desired directory. E.g. by using [file(COPY)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#copy) command. List of files to copy can be obtained using `file(GLOB)`, like in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24311917/3440745):

```cmake
file(GLOB UP_HEADERS /path/to/up/src/*.h)
file(COPY ${UP_HEADERS} DESTINATION /path/to/some/dir/include/up)
```

Comment: Hmmm.  Or maybe the OP can work some magic with symlinks.

Comment: No support for compilers to do that sort of thing. Yeah, I sort of guessed that would be the answer, but you never know until you actually ask! Thanks, and thanks for the copy suggestion too.