# Displaying a target's list of linked libraries in cmake

Tags: cmake

Is there a way to print a list the filenames for the libraries linked into a target via the target_link_libraries command

or even better, have all a target's dependencies copied to a specific folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually not<sup>(*)</sup>.

However, you can use a cmake variable to collect the name of the libraries that you want to link (using the [`set( ...`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html) or the [`list(APPEND ...`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/list.html) command), and then use this variable in your `target_link_libraries` command:

```
target_link_libraries(<targetname> ${YOUR_CMAKE_VARIABLE})
```

The same variable can also be used to create your copy commands (for example using [this custom target](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15696080/2436175))

---

<sub>(*) A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22021312/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-dependencies-of-cmake-target), and it got no definitive answer.</sub>

Answer (score 74):

```
get_target_property(OUT Target LINK_LIBRARIES)
message(STATUS ${OUT})
```

Comment: I think it's a better solution for now.

Answer (score 10):

I realise this doesn't fully answer the question with regards doing it *within cmake*, but I faced a similar problem and thought I should share my solution.

First, in your source directory ("project"):

```
$ mkdir build && cd build
$ cmake ..
```

Then, use graphviz to create a dot file, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22035388/1728179):

```
$ cmake --graphviz=graph.dot .
```

Then, strip out the dependencies from the graph for your target (let's call it "foo"):

```
$ sed -n 's/.*label="\(.*\)"\s.*/\1/p' graph.dot.foo > foo_dependencies.txt
```

Now, remove the clutter:

```
$ rm graph.dot*
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, all linked libraries to a given target TARGET are in the build.../CMakeFiles/TARGET.dir/link.txt.

For instance, TARGET=dirac.x,

```
.../build_intel17_mkl_i8/.less CMakeFiles/dirac.x.dir/link.txt
```

There will be a large number of linked libraries:

```
/cvmfs/it.gsi.de/compiler/intel/17.0/compilers_and_libraries_2017.4.196/linux/bin/intel64/ifort  -Wl,-E  -w -assume byterecl -g -traceback -DVAR_IFORT -i8 -w -assume byterecl -g -traceback -DVAR_IFORT -i8 -O3 -ip CMakeFiles/dirac.x.dir/src/main/main.F90.o  -o dirac.x  -L/tmp/milias-work/software/qch/dirac/devel_trunk/build_intel17_mkl_i8/external/lib  -L/tmp/milias-work/software/qch/dirac/devel_trunk/build_intel17_mkl_i8/external/gen1int-build/external/lib  -L/tmp/milias-work/software/qch/dirac/devel_trunk/build_intel17_mkl_i8/external/pelib-build/external/lib -Wl,-rpath,/tmp/milias-work/software/qch/dirac/devel_trunk/build_intel17_mkl_i8/external/lib:/tmp/milias-work/software/qch/dirac/devel_trunk/build_intel17_mkl_i8/external/gen1int-build/external/lib:/tmp/milias-work/software/qch/dirac/devel_trunk/build_intel17_mkl_i8/external/pelib-build/external/lib: libobjlib.dirac.x.a src/pelib/libpelib_interface.a external/lib/libstieltjes.a -limf -lsvml -lirng -lstdc++ -lm -lipgo -ldecimal -lstdc++ -lgcc -lgcc_s -lirc -lsvml -lc -lgcc -lgcc_s -lirc_s -ldl -lc external/pcmsolver/install/lib/libpcm.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so -limf -lsvml -lirng -lstdc++ -lm -lipgo -ldecimal -lstdc++ -lgcc -lgcc_s -lirc -lsvml -lc -lgcc -lgcc_s -lirc_s -ldl -lc /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so src/libxcfun_fortran_bindings.a external/xcfun-build/src/libxcfun.a external/lib/libpelib.a libgen1int_interface.a external/lib/libgen1int.a -Wl,--start-group /cvmfs/it.gsi.de/compiler/intel/17.0/compilers_and_libraries_2017.4.196/linux/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_lapack95_ilp64.a -lmkl_intel_ilp64 -qopenmp -Wl,--end-group -Wl,--start-group -lmkl_intel_ilp64 -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core -lpthread /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so -qopenmp -Wl,--end-group external/pcmsolver/install/lib/libpcm.a external/xcfun-build/src/libxcfun.a external/lib/libpelib.a external/lib/libgen1int.a /cvmfs/it.gsi.de/compiler/intel/17.0/compilers_and_libraries_2017.4.196/linux/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_lapack95_ilp64.a -lmkl_intel_ilp64 -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core -lpthread /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so -lirng -ldecimal -lstdc++
```