# Configure_file one time it creates a directory and its subdirectories and one time it doesn't

Tags: c++, cmake

I  am trying to copy files from one destination to another by using `configure_file`. I found the following solution [How to copy directory from source tree to binary tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697560/how-to-copy-directory-from-source-tree-to-binary-tree).

```
function(USR_copy_directory srcDir destDir)
    make_directory(${destDir})
    file(GLOB_RECURSE files RELATIVE ${srcDir} ${srcDir}/*)
    foreach(file ${files})
        set(srcFile ${srcDir}/${file})
        if(NOT IS_DIRECTORY ${srcFile})
            configure_file(${srcFile} ${destDir}/${file} COPYONLY)
        endif(NOT IS_DIRECTORY ${srcFile})
    endforeach(file)
endfunction()
```

This solution allowed me to do the job. But when I tried to place the `for` in another function it stopped creating directories. It just flat copied the files without preserving the structure. Basically both snippets of code are the same, it's just I remove the `for` loop and placed it in another function, that's all. What am I doing wrong?

```
function(USR_copy_directory srcDir destDir)
    make_directory(${destDir})
    file(GLOB_RECURSE files RELATIVE ${srcDir} ${srcDir}/*)
    set(srcFile "")
    foreach(file ${files}) #this for loop allows me to append file and path
        list(APPEND srcFile "${srcDir}/${file}")
    endforeach(file)
    USR_copy_files("${srcFile}" ${destDir})
endfunction()


function(USR_copy_files files destDir)
    foreach(file ${files})
        if(NOT IS_DIRECTORY ${file})
            get_filename_component(filename ${file} NAME)
            configure_file(${file}  ${destDir}/${filename} COPYONLY)
        endif(NOT IS_DIRECTORY ${file})
    endforeach(file)
endfunction()
```

Answer (score 0):

It copies files recursivly (with sub-directories from the srcDir to the destDir and it is based on the [How to copy directory from source tree to binary tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697560/how-to-copy-directory-from-source-tree-to-binary-tree) answer

```
# Copies files from source directory to destination directory, substituting any
# variables.  Create destination directory if it does not exist.

macro (configure_files srcDir destDir)
    message (STATUS "Configuring directory ${destDir}")
    make_directory (${destDir})

    file (GLOB templateFiles RELATIVE ${srcDir} "${srcDir}/*")
    foreach (templateFile ${templateFiles})
        set(srcTemplatePath ${srcDir}/${templateFile})
        if (NOT IS_DIRECTORY "${srcTemplatePath}")
            message(STATUS "Configuring file ${templateFile}")
            configure_file(
                    "${srcTemplatePath}"
                    "${destDir}/${templateFile}"
                    @ONLY)
        else (NOT IS_DIRECTORY "${srcTemplatePath}")
            configure_files("${srcTemplatePath}" "${destDir}/${templateFile}")
        endif (NOT IS_DIRECTORY "${srcTemplatePath}")
    endforeach (templateFile ${templateFiles})
endmacro (configure_files srcDir destDir)
```

Comment: what?  Sorry i don't understand u just copied my question?

Comment: No, of course. Look at the following if statement:

     if (NOT IS_DIRECTORY "${srcTemplatePath}") <...> else (NOT IS_DIRECTORY "${srcTemplatePath}")<...>endif (NOT IS_DIRECTORY "${srcTemplatePath}")

It allows us to process directories tree recursively with the tree structure preserving

Comment: P.S. It is easily to extend this method with third parameter mask and replace "${srcDir}/*" with "${srcDir}/${mask}" to filter files by the specified mask

Comment: I've understand what is the trouble in your code. You do not call USR_copy_directory in a recursive way. Because of this you do not process subdirectories, but only files. Fix this problem in your code or use my one